# Fix pasted tabular data in Excel (copied from website)

Tags: html, excel, copy-paste

I am copying large amounts of data from a website, but because it is not laid out in a table it is pasting in the following format in Excel:

```
France
Europe

Spain
Europe

Egypt
Africa
```

I am trying to find a way to automate a 'fix' in Excel to convert it to the following format:

```
France    Europe
Spain     Europe
Egypt     Africa
```

I have tried creating a quick Macro to move the lower cells 'up and right' but I am struggling to get it to work. Is there an easy way of doing this that I am missing or will it involve writing a VB function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your column into the one on its immediate right. Delete the top cell from that column with Shift cells up. Filter that column to select blank cells and delete those rows. Then filter your original column to select blank cells and delete those rows.